# Encountering UnidentifiedImageError when Rendering Images in Streamlit App Using Hugging Face API

Tags: python, streamlit, huggingface, text2image

I'm currently developing a Streamlit application that leverages the Hugging Face API to generate images based on user prompts. The application takes user input prompts, sends them to the API, and then displays the generated images back to the user.

here is the code for that:-

```
import streamlit as st
import requests
import io
from PIL import Image


@st.cache_data
def DreamShaper_v7(token,inputs, guide_scale, inference_steps):
    API_URL = "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/SimianLuo/LCM_Dreamshaper_v7"
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"}

    payload = {
        "inputs": inputs,
        "guide_scale": guide_scale,
        "inference_steps": inference_steps
    }
    
    response = requests.post(API_URL, headers=headers, json=payload)
    image_bytes = response.content

    return image_bytes


def display_DreamShaper_v7(token):
    st.markdown("<h1 style='text-align:center;'>DreamShaper v7</h1>", unsafe_allow_html=True)
    st.markdown("<p style='text-align:center;'>You can download the image with right click > save image</p>", unsafe_allow_html=True)

    with st.sidebar:
        st.title("Parameters Tuning")
        st.session_state.GS_val2 = st.slider("Select Guidencescale", key="slider1", min_value=0.1, max_value=10.0, value=9.0, step=0.1, help="how much your prompt effect your image")
        if st.session_state.GS_val2 > 9.9:
            st.session_state.GS_val2 = 10
        st.write('Guidence scale:', st.session_state.GS_val2)

        st.session_state.inference_steps_val2 = st.slider("Select Inference Steps", key="slider2", min_value=50, max_value=200, value=100, step=1, help="Number of inference steps for image generation")
        st.write('Inference Steps:', st.session_state.inference_steps_val2)

        st.subheader("Usage Manual (must Read !)")
        st.markdown("""<ul>
                        <li>DreamShaper v7</l1>
                        <li>It convert your text prompts into image</l1>
                        <li>When your prompts contains any hateful or malicious text it wont give you image, instead it might give you error or a blank image so dont do it !</l1>
                        <li>Sometimes it migth give you error even when you give legit prompt in that case try changing prompt a little or clear cache data from above settings</l1>
                        <li>There is only 8000 char input allowed in a single prompt so write wisely</li>
                        <li>when your chat history is long it might get Stuck or takes more time to render page (will fix in future), If you encounter this start another session by refreshing page</li>
                        </ul>
                    
                    """,unsafe_allow_html=True)
        st.success("You are Good to go !")

    if "messages_Dream" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state["messages_Dream"] = [
            {"role": "assistant", "content": "What kind of image do you need me to generate? (example: entire universe in glass jar)"}]

    # Display previous prompts and results
    for message in st.session_state.messages_Dream:
        st.chat_message(message["role"]).write(message["content"])
        if "image" in message:
            st.chat_message("assistant").image(message["image"], caption=message["prompt"], use_column_width=True)

    # Prompt Logic
    prompt = st.chat_input("Enter your prompt:")

    if prompt:
        # Input prompt
        st.session_state.messages_Dream.append({"role": "user", "content": prompt})
        st.chat_message("user").write(prompt)

        # Query Stable Diffusion
        headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"}
        image_bytes = DreamShaper_v7(token, prompt, st.session_state.GS_val2, st.session_state.inference_steps_val2)
        # Return Image
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
        msg = f'Here is your image related to "{prompt}"'

        # Show Result
        st.session_state.messages_Dream.append({"role": "assistant", "content": msg, "prompt": prompt, "image": image})
        st.chat_message("assistant").write(msg)
        st.chat_message("assistant").image(image, caption=prompt, use_column_width=True)
```

The application works well for the most part. However, I'm encountering an issue when the user provides the first prompt after launching the application. The error message received is:

error:-

```
UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001A2D16E9CB0>
Traceback:
File "D:\streamlit\Media-generation\.venv\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 535, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "D:\streamlit\Media-generation\app.py", line 42, in <module>
    display_Anime_df(HUGGINGFACE_API_KEY)
File "D:\streamlit\Media-generation\Models\Anime_DF.py", line 74, in display_Anime_df
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\streamlit\Media-generation\.venv\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3309, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(msg)
```

**Interestingly, if I change the prompt or clear the cache data, the application works as expected. It seems like the issue arises only when the first prompt is provided after launching the application.**